# Solving a differential equation with a logarithm

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I want to solve the equation

```
Eqn = Ns - (Sh*theta[x]*Log[1 + tr*theta[x]] - 
      1/(theta[x] + (tr - 1)^(-1))*D[theta[x], {x, 2}]) == 0;
```

and plot their solution **x versus Ns**
I have written code But it does not work.

```
sol[Sh_] := 
  Table[{Ns, 
    theta[0] /. 
     First@NDSolve[{Ns - (Sh*theta[x]*Ln[1 + tr*theta[x]] - 
            1/(theta[x] + (tr - 1)^(-1))*D[theta[x], {x, 2}]) == 0, 
        theta[1] == 1, theta'[0] == -0.250}, theta, {x, 0, 1}]}, {Ns, 
    0, 5, 0.1}];

pt1 = ListLinePlot[{Evaluate[sol[0]], Evaluate[sol[8]], 
   Evaluate[sol[10]], Evaluate[sol[80]], Evaluate[sol[50]], 
   Evaluate[sol[23]]},   
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Black, Cyan, Pink}, 
  PlotLegends ->  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {X, Ns}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Red, Bold],Axes -> False]
```

please help me

Comment: Is `Ln[1 + Tr*theta[x]] `   a function? Then you should show it to us. If you mean product, you should write `Ln (1 + Tr*theta[x]) ` and give Ln a value.

Comment: If `Ln` is meant to be the natural logarithm, you should code `Log`.  Also `Tr` is a *Mathematica* function that takes the trace of a matrix, or of a tensor.  It is common practice to use variable names that begin with a lowercase letter, to avoid conflicts with *Mathematica* keywords.

Comment: The parameter ` Tr` is undefined!

Answer (score 5):

Try `ParametricNDSolveValue`

```
θ = 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {Ns - (Sh*theta[x]*Log[1 + Tr*theta[x]] -1/(theta[x] + 
       (Tr - 1)^(-1))*D[theta[x], {x, 2}]) == 0,
     theta[1] == 1, theta'[0] == -0.250}, 
    theta, {x, 0, 1}, {Ns, Sh, Tr}]
```

This gives the solution  `θ` depending on the parameters `Ns, Sh, Tr`
Plot the solution for examplary parameters `Ns==1, Sh==.5, Tr==-.1`

```
Plot[θ[1, .5, -.1][x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Result for variing `Ns` (`x==0`) :

```
Table[θ[ns, .5, -.1][0], {ns, 0, 5, 1}]
(*{1.26001, 1.50832, 2.18313, -0.521793, 0.421456, 0.621914}*)
```

Comment: the answer is useful. I want to plot the solution x versus Ns  please help me how to do it

Comment: Try `Plot[θ[ns, .5, -.1][0], {ns, 0, 5}]` or `ListPlot[Table[θ[ns, .5, -.1][0], {ns, 0, 5, 1}]]`